# How are shorter GUID user friendly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, guid

I just came accross this [blog](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.nl/2013/10/adding-email-confirmation-to-aspnet.html) which uses [ShortGuid](http://www.singular.co.nz/blog/archive/2007/12/20/shortguid-a-shorter-and-url-friendly-guid-in-c-sharp.aspx) to create registration validation tokens.

When i tried to open the link which said **A shorter and URL friendly Guid** it seems that the link redirects to some other link. It opens some other language site.

But I have few questions, How can a shorter Guid be user friendly? And when should I use it?

Comment: @DavinTryon URL character limits are 2k, if you are concerned about hitting that the problem is deeper than just how you format GUIDs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a copy/past benefit as well. If i understand correctly, it is not about nice URLs, but about validation tokens. A lot of people copy/pase codes by double clicking, and then the Sguid (ShortGuid) is indeed more user friendly. Try it:

Xy0MVKupFES9NpmZ9TiHcw

540c2d5f-a9ab-4414-bd36-9999f5388773

Comment: good point but you could get that by just stripping the -'s out of the normal guid, most guid parsers will still be fine with that

Comment: thats true, just realised it. +1 for that

Answer (score 5):

> How can a shorter Guid be user friendly?

If your users type in URLs by hand instead of clicking links, so not very likely.

> And when should I use it?

All characters in a GUID (`A-F`, `0-9`, `-`) are URL-safe, so 'safety' isn't really an argument.

You may want to consider it for aesthetical reasons, or for ease of copy-pasting the URL.

Comment: The braces that are frequently used around guids (`{` and `}`), tend to end up being URL escaped, making copying a GUID out of a url (to use elsewhere)...inconvenient.  Sometimes even the dashes end up being URL escaped, making it worse.

Answer (score 2):

Guid's are generally expressed in base-16 (using 0-9 and A-F).  This makes the strings long.  The same amount of data can be expressed in a shorter string if you use more characters (0-9, a-z, A-Z, and other special characters like _ or @).

While they dont make a difference to your code at all, long GUIDs are ugly looking to have in URLs or anything a user might see so you can convert them to a shorter format that is still not very pretty but takes up less space.

Somebody might argue that the shorter format requires less bandwidth but the practical savings are negligible.

Answer (score 1):

> How can a shorter Guid be user friendly?

You answered your own question, *in* the question. It's pretty obvious: `7A9D35A3` (shorter) is much easier to remember/type than `7A9D35A3-4999-4130-8E2B-EB0447D942FA`.

> And when should I use it?

An example would be to use it as a reference. Some examples:

- "An error has occurred, please contact support. Reference: 7A9D35A3"
- "Your booking was confirmed! Booking code: 7A9D35A3"

Answer (score 0):

What about using a db table to map ID with GUID. Something like

```
ID      GUID
1000    540c2d5f-a9ab-4414-bd36-9999f5388773
1001    123c2d5f-a9ab-4414-bd36-9999f5388773
1002    567c2d5f-a9ab-4414-bd36-9999f5388773
```

It would be much easier to scale or migrate then using ID in each db table, and you end up with a clean ID.